# Trying to create two side by side box plots using data from the same variable in R

Tags: r, csv, statistics, boxplot

I'm new to R. I'm trying to create a boxplot for two different categories, however the results of those two categories are complied in the same variable. I've used the count function to order the variables so they align with the category they are for.

I would like to create two side-by-side boxplots in R using the same variable. The image contains the code I'm trying to use and the error message I receive.
[Image of my attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gmPVl.png)

Comment: Please share a few rows of sample data in a copy/pasteable format. Please add your code as copy/pasteable text, not as a picture.

Comment: The index vector `29:59` has length `59 - 29 + 1 == 31` and the first vector, `1:28` has length `28 - 1 + 1`. That's the error.

Answer (score 1):

The "~" in your boxplot() function plots one variable against another (the first variable on the y-axis and the second on the x-axis).  For a boxplot the x variable might be categorical.

You might try:

```
par(mfrow = c(1, 2))
boxplot(QuestionTwo$seizure[1:28])
boxplot(QuestionTwo$seizure[29:59])
```